# Add (row, col) as arguments to elementwise numpy function?

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy very naturally does elementwise manipulations. However often I want to also have the position of an element when writing the function, like:

```
def neighbor_count(arr, row, col):
 hood = arr[row-1:row+1, col-1, col+1]
 return np.sum(hood)-arr[row,col]
```

I could just create a nested for loop:

```
for (i, row) in enumerate(arr[1:-1]):
 for (j, col) in enumerate (row[1:-1]):
  c = neighbor_count(arr, i+1, j+1)
```

But that feels like giving up and going back to how I would work in c++.

Any clever Pythonic solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a small example with your expected result. For example, `np.random.seed(0); 
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 25).reshape([5, 5])`  And then use that array to illustrate what you are trying to achieve with your expected result included.

Comment: Do you want: `col-1:col+1`?  Is `hood` supposed to be a (3,3) set of element surrounding (and including) `arr[row,col]`?  And purpose of the `[1:-1]` is to avoid running off-the-end?  There are some moving window or image convolution approaches which are faster.

Comment: Please show complete code, a sufficient input and an expected output.  Your question is too fragmentary to give a reliably useful answer to.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`numpy.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html), which works about like `enumerate` does but for `ndarray` structures.

I can't provide an exact answer to your particular use case, since it's not altogether clear how you're trying to combine the resulting values, but the basic idea is this.

```
for (r, c), i in np.ndenumerate(arr):
  do_something()
```

Note that `ndenumerate` returns an iterator, so all the `itertools` functionality you're used to should work on it.